# CodeIgniter Upload Class file_ext_tolower not working, even on localhost

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I have a really weird problem. I'm using the CodeIgniter Upload Class for managing the upload of a simple jpg image. If I upload a file with extension .JPG, even if I set the property file_ext_tolower to TRUE, my file gets uploaded with the .JPG extension. Which is something that I don't want! Here is some code..

```
$this->load->library('upload');

$config['upload_path'] = './resources/img/content';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg';
$config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
$config['file_ext_tolower'] = TRUE;
$config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

$this->upload->initialize($config, true);

if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('cover')) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message','Cover: ' . $this->upload->display_errors());
    redirect('admin');
    break;
} else {
    // Whatever
}
```

Problem is, this doesn't run even on localhost. It always goes ahead and uploads the file with the .JPG. I just cannot understand. I'm using CodeIgniter 3.1.0 on both the server and the localhost. Any thoughts? On the server I've also enabled the fileinfo extension in the php.ini.

Another thing that this brings is that..if I have a file named myfile.JPG and myfile.jpg, CodeIgniter isn't able to see that they're the same file..which is ultimately what would be likely it does if only file_ext_tolower was working properly.

On server, myfile.JPG gets saved as myfile.JPG. I think that, when file_ext_tolower is set to TRUE, it should save as myfile.jpg...and eventually, before doing that, actually search for another file with this name..if file with this name is already on the server, it should follow the **overwrite** setting: either overwrite it or rename with a progressive number.

Answer (score 0):

I have solution for you :)

Create file: application/libraries/MY_Upload.php

```
<?php 
class MY_Upload extends CI_Upload
{
    /**
     * Force filename to lowercase
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $file_name_tolower = FALSE;


    function _prep_filename($filename)
    {
        if ($this->mod_mime_fix === FALSE OR $this->allowed_types === '*' OR ($ext_pos = strrpos($filename, '.')) === FALSE)
        {
            return $filename;
        }

        $ext = substr($filename, $ext_pos);
        $filename = substr($filename, 0, $ext_pos);

        //change ext tolower
        $filename = ($this->file_name_tolower)?strtolower($filename):$filename;
        //change ext tolower
        $ext = ($this->file_ext_tolower)?strtolower($ext):$ext;

        return str_replace('.', '_', $filename).$ext;
    }
}
```

I modyfication **file_ext_tolower** and add **file_name_tolower**

**Example for file: coVEr.JPG**

```
...
$config['file_ext_tolower'] = TRUE;
$config['file_name_tolower'] = TRUE;
...
```

Result: **cover.jpg**

```
...
$config['file_ext_tolower'] = TRUE;
$config['file_name_tolower'] = FALSE;
...
```

Result: **coVEr.jpg**

```
...
$config['file_ext_tolower'] = FALSE;
$config['file_name_tolower'] = TRUE;
...
```

Result: **cover.JPG**

```
...
$config['file_ext_tolower'] = FALSE;
$config['file_name_tolower'] = FALSE;
...
```

Result: **coVEr.JPG**

Comment: Does this solution takes into account to check if a file with that given new name already exists on the server? Cause I see the code but I don't see a line which should check this. It's important that it checks for file with same name and DOES NOT overwrite it.

Comment: Also..i see you use again file_ext_tolower. But, in the question I said, it's NOT WORKING. If it was working properly, I wouldn't need all this workaround. That's the point..

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It is silly mistake, no matter how much code i edit on this file also no effect on result. So I start guess I refer to wrong file :

1. maybe member-site file but I edit admin-site file.
2. maybe order-model file but I edit invoice-model file.
   After echo "alert("abc");" to find the correct file, then i edit the code then finally I get the result output perfectly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).